# Git: Safely roll back to a previous master

Tags: git

I need to revert my `master` to a previous merge. Most of the answers on here provide ways to destructively do this (meaning, I won't be able to re-roll it forward, and I'll lose all of the work since that commit).

How can I revert to a previous commit, while still saving my current master?

Comment: Do you need the *name* `master` to identify the earlier commit?  Or, do you just want to extract the earlier commit into your work-tree so that you can see and work with its files? Or, do you want to create a new branch name that identifies that earlier commit?

Comment: And do you mean revert or reset? Revert is safe; it makes a new commit that undoes the _effect_ of some commits. Reset can take some planning depending on what your purpose is, as you can effectively _lose_ some actual commits otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> Most of the answers on here provide ways to destructively do this (meaning, I won't be able to re-roll it forward, and I'll lose all of the work since that commit).

None of the answers here provides that. Reverting `master` to a previous merge means rehanging a label.  Git remembers where labels have been. Anything reachable in the last month is still there waiting for you.  So rehang the label:

```
git checkout -B master that.previous.merge
```

and you don't like what you see, put it back with

```
git checkout -B master master@{1}
```

Use `git reflog master` to see all the places `master` has been in the last month or so.  Same with any ref, including "whatever I had checked out last monday morning":

```
git checkout -B master HEAD@{last.monday.morning}
```

or if you want to see some options, check out whatever looks interesting from the list `git reflog @{last.monday.morning}` shows you, because `HEAD` (git's usual default ref) is just a ref to whatever you've got checked out, so it's got its own reflog.

Comment: Where can I find definitive documentation of what the valid date specification possibilities are?

Comment: @matt it's about as ad-hoc a date parser as I could ever imagine, the definitive documentation seems to be `date.c` in the source. rfc822 dates work, anything past that is human convenience, in "whatever works" territory.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m discovering. :(